# how to make a phonegap app load a url in page without opening it with safari

Tags: iphone

how is it possible using html/js to make an iphone native app build with phonegap or other html based app makers to load an url in a navigation controller without leaving the app. (sort of like the fb iphone app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Plugin in your Xcode project. This one was specifically created by the guys on the PhoneGap team to address the situation you desribe.

Chec out the code in http://github.com/purplecabbage/PhoneGap-Plugins/tree/master/ChildBrowser. This allows you 'spawn' a new controller (from your basic PhoneGap Native app) which pops up and has a browser in the controller. A button allows the user 'close' the view and you return to the native app.